# Delete component from imported model (NOT instantiated GameObject)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

Recently I've been working with the `Asset Importer`/`Model Importer` in Unity, and I successfully managed to remove the `Camera` and `Light` components on an **imported 3D model** using `C#` script. However my **problem** is I'm failing to remove the `Animator` component that seems to be on almost every model.
The code I'm using:

```
importedModel = (ModelImporter)AssetImporter.GetAtPath("Assets/Resources/" + Path.GetFileName(fileName));
importedModel.importAnimation = false;//This is NOT working (Model still has Animator)
importedModel.importCameras = false; //This is working
importedModel.importLights = false; //This is working
importedModel.meshCompression = ModelImporterMeshCompression.High;
AssetDatabase.WriteImportSettingsIfDirty(importedModel.assetPath);
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

Also another thing I have tried is to get the actual `Animator` component from the model and then **destroy** it. I have successfully obtained a reference to the component using the following code:

```
foreach (Animator animatorComponent in Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Animator>())        
    DestroyImmediate(animatorComponent, true);
```

However when I use the `DestroyImmediate` the component still exists.
How could I **remove / deactivate** this `Animator` component from my 3D model?

Comment: Hi, what about set `ModelImporter.animationType` (Animator generation mode) to `None`?  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporter-animationType.html

Comment: @mayo Hi, thanks for responding. I will try that tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @mayo It works! That is exactly what I wanted. Could you provide an answer so I could mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I posted an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [ModelImporter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporter.html), you can specify the `Animator generation mode` using the [animationType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporter-animationType.html) property.

The [options](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporterAnimationType.html) are:

- None
- Legacy
- Generic
- Human

---

In your case, this would make the trick;

```
importedModel.animationType = ModelImporterAnimationType.None;
```